# Accessing a function inside a class from another class in Python

Tags: python

```
class Read_serial:
    i=0
    file = open('nmea.txt', 'r')
    txt = file.read()
    #print txt
    s=txt.splitlines()

    for data in s:
                gpgga=nmea.GPGGA()
                gpgga.parse(data)
                lat=gpgga.latitude
```

Hi.. I am new to Python. I have a class Read_serial which reads a set of GPS data. It's stored in a variable lat.
I want to access this 'lat' in another class in which i have a function that displays it's value in a GTK window. As the value of 'lat' changes the value in window should also change. Kindly suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Could you provide an example of where you call this class? The `for` code should probably be in a function.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the class properly. Classes are meant for objects that store and operate on data. Typically something that has to retain state.

```
class Point(object)
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        super().__init__()

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    # end constructor

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
...
```

so you probably only need a function for that

```
def read_gps(filename)
    """Read a file with nmea gps messages."""

    lats = []        
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
         for line in file.readlines():
             gpgga=nmea.GPGGA()
             gpgga.parse(line)
             lat = gpgga.latitude

             # do something with lat
             # call class function.
             #     point = Point() # If called somewhere else before the for loop.
             #     point.move(lat, 0)


             # GUIs like PySide have signals that you can emit.
             lats.append(lat)
    # end with (close file)

    return lats
# end read_gps


latitude_vals = read_gps("nmea.txt")
# use the returned value
```

In addition there is a nmea2 library out there that may be easier to use. Also reading in a file is very quick and a file is a static object, so you may want to connect directly to the gps with pyserial.